# Is this stochastic process a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I have the following process:

$X_t=tB_t-\int^{t}_{0}B_s \ ds$ where $B_t $ is a Brownian motion.

Is this a Gauß-process and/or a martingale?

Can someone help me with this? And how can I calculate the $\int^{t}_{0}B_s \ ds$ part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints: (Martingale)** Fix $s \leq t$.

1. Write $$\mathbb{E}(t B_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{E}(t (B_t-B_s) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) + \mathbb{E}(t B_s \mid \mathcal{F}_s).$$ For the first term, use that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has independent increments, i.e. $B_t-B_s$ and $\mathcal{F}_s$ are independent, and $B_t-B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$. What about the second term?
2. Use the identity $$\int_0^t B_r \, dr = \int_0^s B_r \, dr + \int_s^t B_r \, dr = \int_0^s B_r \, dr + \int_s^t (B_r-B_s) \, dr+ (t-s)B_s$$ and a similar reasoning as in step 1 to calculate $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t B_r \, dr \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right).$$
3. Conclude.

**Hints: (Gaussian)**

1. Set $t_i := \frac{i}{n} t$. Since $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is Gaussian, we know that $(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n})$ is (jointly) Gaussian. Deduce from this fact that $$X_t^n := t B_{t_n} - \sum_{i=1}^n B_{t_i} (t_{i+1}-t_i)$$ is Gaussian.
2. Recall that $X_t^n \to X_t$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.
3. Conclude.

**Remark:** This argumentation does not use Itô's formula. However, Itô's formula provides us with an alternative solution: It follows easily from Itô's formula that

$$X_t = \int_0^t s\, dB_s.$$

Since stochastic integrals are martingales (... at least if the integrand is "nice") and integrals of the form

$$\int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s$$

are Gaussian for any determinstic function $f$ whenever the integral exists, we find that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is Gaussian and a martingale.

Comment: Can you explain why $\mathbb{E} (\int_s^t (B_r-B_s) \, dr+ (t-s)B_s|\mathcal{F}_s)=0$ ?

Comment: @kanbhold Where did I claim this...? The expression does *not* equal $0$.

Comment: Ok, then I don't see why is that a martingale.

Comment: @kanbhold Without any further details (or your computations), there is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: I don't understand this part: $ \int_s^t B_r \, dr = \int_0^s B_r \, dr + \int_s^t (B_r-B_s) \, dr+ (t-s)B_s$ especially that $(t-s)B_s$

Comment: @kanbhold I have never claimed that this holds true; there is something missing on the left-hand side. Anyway: $$\begin{align*} \int_s^t B_r \, dr &= \int_s^t ((B_r-B_s)+B_s) \, dr \\ &= \int_s^t (B_r-B_s) \, dr + \int_s^t B_s \, dr \\ &= \int_s^t (B_r-B_s) \, dr + (t-s) B_s. \end{align*}$$

Comment: This is the only part I don't understand: $\int_s^t B_r \, dr=(t-s) B_s$

Comment: @kanbhold This is not what I wrote. Neither in my last comment nor in my answer. Please read both of them more carefully.

Comment: in your comment, the last 2 rows are the same except that instead $\int_s^t B_r \, dr$ you wrote $(t-s) B_s$. I don't see why aren't they equal then?

Comment: @kanbhold I wrote $\int_s^t B_s \, dr$, not $\int_s^t B_r \, dr$. This makes a huge difference.

Comment: Oh, really, thanks! It is clear now!

Comment: @saz I have one question please, how can I compute $\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t B_r \, dr \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right)$ using the identity above ? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @Joel Where exactly are you stuck? I already gave a hint (=the identity) so what is stopping you from following this hint?

Comment: @saz when I use the identity inside the expectation, i take the first term out because it is $\mathcal{F}_s$-meas, and also for the last term, but for the second term I don't know what I'm gonna do.

Comment: @Joel I see. Use the independence of the increments, i.e. use that $B_r-B_s$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_s$ for $r \geq s$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Itô formula :
$$d(tB_t)=B_tdt+tdB_t$$
So that
$$X_t=\int_0^t sdB_s$$
which is a Wiener integral (Gaussian) thus a martingale.